# Iterate through loop and return string from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to iterate through this array and return to HTML quotes from the array one by one - after pressing each time the button?

This is my piece of code i can't figure out:

```
var quotes = ['"Time you enjoy wasting is not wasted time."',
'"You can have it all. Just not all at once."', 
'"They say I am old-fashioned, and live in the past, but sometimes I think
progress progresses too fast!"'];

document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", newQuote);
function newQuote(){
  for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = quotes[i];  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use a counter to keep track of the next quote's index** and wrap it around once you've reached the last one:

```js
var nextQuote = 0;

var quotes = [
  '"Time you enjoy wasting is not wasted time."',
  '"You can have it all. Just not all at once."',
  '"They say I am old-fashioned, and live in the past, but sometimes I think progress progresses too fast!"'
];

function newQuote() {
  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = quotes[nextQuote];
  nextQuote = (nextQuote + 1) % quotes.length;

}
```

```html
<div id='quote'></div>
<button onClick='newQuote()'>Next Quote</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var quotes = ['"Time you enjoy wasting is not wasted time."',
'"You can have it all. Just not all at once."', 
'"They say I am old-fashioned, and live in the past, but sometimes I think
progress progresses too fast!"'];

var quoteNumber = 0;
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", newQuote);
function newQuote(){
  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = quotes[quoteNumber];
  quoteNumber++;
  if(quoteNumber == quotes.length) quoteNumber = 0;  
}
```